# Returning an Object[][] gives NullPointerException

Tags: object, nullpointerexception, return

I have an Access database which I need to retrieve all fields except the first and last and display it in a JTable. Everything works perfectly fine when I create my Object[][] but when i return it, i get a NullPointerException. I tried to find where there could be a null value in the database by printing the whole object out but that works fine and no values are null. Why would returning the Object[][] give me a NullPointerException and how can i fix it?

the stack trace is:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
    public Object [] [] SetTrainingLogTable() throws SQLException
    {

    DatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection();

    //Retrieves all the data from the TrainingLog table
    ResultSet resultset = connection.SelectStatements("SELECT * FROM TrainingLog");

    //Retrieves the number of entries
    ResultSet numberofworkouts = connection.SelectStatements("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM    TrainingLog");

    int count = numberofworkouts.getInt(1);
    number = count;

    String[][] table = new String [count] [6];   

    //Number to incriment for while loops
    int row = 0;

    String date = "";

    while(row<count)
    {
        date = resultset.getString(2);
        table [row][0] = calculate.RefineDate(date); 
        table [row][1] = resultset.getString(3);
        table [row][2] = resultset.getString(4);
        table [row][3] = resultset.getString(5);
        table [row][4] = resultset.getString(6);
        table [row][5] = resultset.getString(7);
        resultset.next();  
        row++;
    }

    Object[][] data = table;

    connection.close();

    return data;
}
```

I ran a debugger and it only gives the error when the return line is run.

Comment: The return statement as written couldn't generate a NullPointerException. Can you post the full stack trace and point out which lines they correspond to?

Answer (score 0):

It's best to post the stack trace and tell which line is raising the error.  However, the typical way of writing such code is:

```
Connection con = ...;
Statement  st  = ...;
ResultSet  rs  = ...;
while (rs.next()) {
    // ...
}
```

The result set starts out pointing *before the first row*.  `rs.next()` returns whether there is a next row, and advances to it if it exists.  Can you rewrite it in that style?

Other suggestions:

1. Can you create an actual object type instead of using `Object[]` to store the data from each row?  Call it `Workout`.
2. Can you use a `List<Workout>` instead of your `Object[][]`?
3. Is the date stored in the database as a SQL DATE or TIMESTAMP?  Then, don't convert it to a Java `String`: use `java.sql.Date` or `java.util.Date`.  At work, I have a large old program that uses strings for dates, and it uses different formats to convert the values at different times. It's pretty miserable.
4. Don't use `SELECT *`.  Give the names of the columns to return.  Use the `rs.getString("column_name")` syntax.
5. There's no need to set one variable to the returned table and immediately set another variable to it.
6. Closing the connection or statement should be done in a finally block, or by try-with-resources.